# Canvas layers and positioning

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having hard time on figuring out how should i do in order to set a proper size to the following canvases

```
<div id="canvasesdiv" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: table-cell;  position: relative; width:578px; height:415.5px">
  <canvas id="c1"      style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>   
  <canvas id="c2"      style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>
  <canvas id="c3"      style="z-index: 3; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>
  <canvas id="c4"      style="z-index: 4; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>
  <canvas id="c5"      style="z-index: 5; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>
```

Cleary width and height are parsed wrongly (html is expecting : and the values in px) but somehow the canvases are drawn in their full dimension. Instead if i use something like:

```
  <canvas id="c1"     style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>   
  <canvas id="c2"     style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>
  <canvas id="c3"     style="z-index: 3; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>
  <canvas id="c4"     style="z-index: 4; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>
  <canvas id="c5"     style="z-index: 5; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>
```

or with

```
... width: 500px; height: 500px;"
```

The canvases are all cropped down to `300x150` (chrome default) no matter what.

The problem is that position:absolute is a must in order to have layers. How can i do in order to define a dimension without ruin the canvas quality and make it so it stays in the given boundary?

See this example, can you fix it so that the position is absolute but the size is whatever you want and centered? [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/ecTCD/96).

If I add position:absolute, the overlay works but it is out of the div bound, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/ecTCD/98).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ecTCD/99/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting HTML `width` and `height` attributes in the `style` attributes, which should hold `css`. If you check the dev tools, you will see the relevent rules are striked through. Just use css to style them. Even better, place them in the `<style/>` tag or in an external stylesheet

Not good:

```
<canvas style="... width="680" height="435"></canvas>
```

Good:

```
<canvas style="... width: 680px; height: 435px;"></canvas>
```

Or: just close the double quote, and use the attributes anyway (although css is the better solution)

Comment: Hum, `<canvas style="... width: 680px; height: 435px;"></canvas>`is not good either  : canvases content will be stretched to this size but will still default to 300 * 150 px. The good behavior is to keep the aspectRatio between canvas' height and width attribute and their stylings (the easiest way being not to set their sizes in CSS at all).

Comment: That's what i am saying, question is how do i achieve it?